# example project for Keil RTOS thread usage on ARM STM32F4xx

Tags: gcc, arm, rtos, keil, cmsis

I need to port some ARM source code from GCC toolchain with FreeRTOS over to Keil toochain (IDE and debugger) and Keil's RTOS.

I'm looking for a simple example Keil uVision5 project that has simple thread examples.

Answer (score 1):

uVision Keil IDE > Pack Installer toolbar command > Examples tab > CMSIS-RTOS Blinky > Copy command
...installs the example and even opens the example's uVision project.